# keep old value in form laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I have form where i have 2 buttons one is **save and add another** and 2nd **save and exit** i have a field **list** in my form i want if user click on save and add another the list should be same as it was saved last time.in my db i have **list_id** field for list
here is my

**create method**

```
    public function create()
    {
        $lists = DB::table('lists')->select('id', 'name')->get();
        $page_data = [
                        'title' => trans('mumara.subscribers.add_new_sub.title'),
                        'action' => 'add'
                     ];
        $list_id = isset($_GET['list_id']) ? $_GET['list_id'] : null;

   return view('subscriber.create')->with(compact('page_data', 'lists', 'list_id'));
    }
```

Here id my **list field**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Add List
                            <span class="required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select class="form-control select2" name="list_id" id="list-id" {{ ($page_data['action'] == 'edit') ? 'disabled' : '' }} >
                                <option value="0">Choose a List</option>
                                @foreach($lists as $list)
                                    <option value="{{ $list->id }}" {{ (isset($subscriber->list_id) && ($list->id  == $subscriber->list_id)) || (!empty($list_id) && $list->id == $list_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                    {{ $list->name  }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Buttons are as**

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" name="save_add" class="btn green" value="save_add">Save & Add Another</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="save_add" class="btn green" value="save_exit">Save & Exit</button>

                    </div>
```

Now i want if user clicks on save and add another button list should be same as last time it saved 
Please help to fix it
I know a little that i should pas list id with create but dont know how can i do

Comment: when you click "Save & Add Another", after saving data send POST data back to the page through controller and then in each filed check corresponding value is there in POST? if yes then show the value otherwise empty. So your each input seems something like this:- `<input name="GDP" type="text" value = "<?php if(isset($post_data['GDP']) && !empty($post_data['GDP'])){echo $post_data['GDP'];}?>">`

Comment: Sorry not understand what you are saying clarify please @Anant

Comment: you need to check how to show posted data again after form submit? check this and you will understand

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `resource` route where `create` function for displaying a create from. and `store` function for storing to the database.
For example for showing create form you could use :

```
public function create()
    {
        // this is where the create view is you can change as yours
        return view('users.form');
    }
```

and when you're trying to get the old data just return the data like this :

```
    public function store(Request $request)

    {

        // this is where you save your data 
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');

        $user->save();

        // this is where your return your old data
        return view('users.form',$user);
    }
```

Comment: ok suppose i click on save and add another now create form will show again to me hoe there will be list id as it was added last @Gujarat Santana

Comment: @the data that you're returning in `function store(Request $request)` is the same as before, and you can access the id by in this case above`$user->id`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#old-input

```
$request->flash();
```

From the doc: The flash method on the Illuminate\Http\Request class will flash the current input to the session so that it is available during the user's next request to the application.